# How to get Date from input type="date" in a Groovy Template?

Tags: java, html, groovy

please how can recovered a date object from input type 'date'..
as the return is a character string

to create a new Date object instance

```
Date :<input type="date" name="anniversaire">
Date d = new Date () / / from input
```

Comment: Is this in `juzu` again?

Comment: hhhhh no juste groovy template with an input type date :)

Comment: Can you show what you mean in the question?  How are you running the template?  How are people entering data?  And what is intercepting the data?

Comment: I have a list of products with production date.                                       I wont to change it according to the selected date from calendar <input type'date'> so the first thing is getting this value, and pass it into setDate Methode for modification (y)

Comment: Yeah, but how are you running the Groovy Template?  How are you showing the input to the user?  And what catches it when they submit the form (I assume they submit the form?). Can you come up with a minimal running example?

Comment: I'm using a integreted IDE :( I just write the code

Comment: But you must have something that the form posts to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a thirdparty library like [moment](http://momentjs.com)

```
moment("11-06-1013", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

or solve all crossbrowser stuff yourself and use something like:

```
new Date("11-06-1013")
```

Comment: thank you Oosterholt.. I would like to do something like this                          anniversaire.getvalue (returned value type Date) and then passed to constructor...I'm using Groovy Template